# Get the value of the nth iteration of a number in excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match

Simply put, I have a number in the Z column and time of day in B and my goal is to retrieve the time of day of the second iteration of the number in Z. If the first time the number x occurs at is 2 pm and the second occurs at 3 pm, I want the time to be retrieved to be 3 pm.

I achieved this with a bunch of volatile formulas and since my file is 9000 rows, it takes 5 good minutes to run and just locks my computer in the meantime. I also cannot run macros because they are banned.

I have been trying to achieve it with index and match since but so far I cannot.
Here is what I have:

`=IF(COUNTIF($Z:$Z, Z2)>1, Z2,"")` that finds the value once.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(Z2,Z:Z,MATCH(Z2,Z:Z,0)+1)),"")
```

that would be supposed to find it a second time but clearly I don't get it.

Thank you for your help, please explain why yours works if you write the answer, I'm interested.

Comment: What do you mean by "volative"? It's not a word, afaik.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that this works just fine:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(B:B,Z:Z=42),2,1),"Not found")
```

I've assumed you're looking for the second occurrence of `42` in column `Z`.

[image: spreadsheet]

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to use only the ranges which are really used.
In this example B1:B11 and Z1:Z11 are used. Adjust ranges to required value. In cell J1 is the searched value.

`=INDEX(B$1:B$11,SMALL(IF(ROW(Z$1:Z$11)*(Z$1:Z$11=J$1)=0,"",ROW(Z$1:Z$11)*(Z$1:Z$11=J$1)),2),0)`

Description

`ROW(Z$1:Z$11)*(Z$1:Z$11=J$1)`  generates an array of the absolute line numbers where a match is found.

`IF(ROW(Z$1:Z$11)*(Z$1:Z$11=J$1)=0,"",ROW(Z$1:Z$11)*(Z$1:Z$11=J$1))` set 0 values to a null string.

`SMALL(..... ,2)` function return the second value in the line numbers.

`INDEX(B$1:B$11, ...... ,0)` function returns the corresponding value in column B of the calculated row.

Comment: Upvoted because it can easily be changed to get the third, fourth etc matching value.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't have access to Filter and had to do it with index/match, you would have to find the first match, then search the rest of the column for the second match and finally add the position of the first match before indexing the time value:

```
=INDEX(B2:B11,MATCH(Z2,INDEX(Z2:Z11,MATCH(Z2,Z2:Z11,0)+1):Z11,0)+MATCH(Z2,Z2:Z11,0),0)
```

[image]